# Ubuntu installer gets stuck with flashing screen

Tags: boot, server, 16.04, system-installation, virtualization

I'm using QEMU to setup a Ubuntu 16.04 Server VM.

I cannot get this done because somewhere at the beginning of the install process, the screen starts flashing and there is nothing more I can do. No matter how long I wait, it's stuck like that (I waited 30 minutes).

Here is a screencast of the issue (this is in rescue mode, but it does the same in install mode): [image: screen flashing]

What is happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Ubuntu instead of Debian on the VM host so I could have a more recent QEMU/KVM/virt-manager and this doesn't seem to be a problem anymore. Not Sure what happened.